# Doubt regarding contractive condition and Cauchy's Theorm.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Before I begin I want to lay emphasis on *the **Contractive Condition*** implying Cauchyness.
**Theorm:**
Let $\left\{x_n\right\}$ be a sequence such that there exists a $0<C<1$ such that
$$
\large\left|x_{n+1}-x_n\right| \leq C\left|x_n-x_{n-1}\right|
$$
Then the sequence $\left\{x_n\right\}$ is Cauchy.
I was working on some assignments and the following question came forth:

---

State true or false:
If $\left(x_n\right)$ satisfies the Cauchy criterion, then there exists an $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $0<\alpha<1$ and $$\large \left|x_{n+1}-x_n\right| \leq \alpha\left|x_n-x_{n-1}\right|$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

---

Now here I don't know if the above theorem is a necessity for sequence being Cauchy or not, but it is definitely sufficient.
I doubt that this is not a necessary condition but not able to work that out.
Any help will be appreciated.

### Edit

I got the answer to my question:
***Conclusion:***
Every contractive sequence is caushy but not the converse!!

Comment: I'm sorry. I flagged this question as duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1171307/contractive-condition-implies-the-sequence-is-cauchy. But it's not a duplicate. I'm sorry.

Comment: @PNDas Hi ,I have already gone through the question you posted but it fails to answer the question which I asked above. The question you posted only talks about sufficient conditions for being caushy not the neccesary part.

Comment: @PNDas I have got my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2142027/is-every-cauchy-sequence-contractive#:~:text=No.,1%20as%20n%E2%86%92%E2%88%9E.  Kindly mark this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking whether every Cauchy is contractive, then the answer is no. Check for $\langle x_n\rangle$ where $x_n:=1/n.$